# Alternate form of Modus tollens applicable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The definition states that

```
not(q)
p--> q
----------
not(p)
```

Is the following form is also true?

```
(q)
not(p-)--> not(q)
----------
(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because "q"  is equivalent to "not(not q)", and "p" is equivalent to "not(not p)".

Comment: ..in classical logic. :)

Comment: @neptun: Do you doubt that was OP's intent, given the content of the question?

Comment: absolutely, i never add smileys unless i'm upset